# Mirror image output from v2 pi camera in motion

Tags: camera, pi-3, motion

can anybody tell me how I can flip the mirror image output in motioneye .I am using a pi3 with a v2 8meg pi camera with the latest pi3 motioneyeos.I have now tested 3 different cameras with the same pi3 running the same pi3 motion software and the results were.
Usb web camera works perfectly.
Pi camera version 1 works perfectly. 
pi camera version 2 works but camera image is mirrored.
Can anybody tell me if this is a os issue or pi camera issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity, didn't you already post [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47446/mirror-image-output-from-pi3-using-v2-camera-in-motioneye/47496#47496)? Did you just forget the password to your original account (you could always reset it and edit the original question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes Grant it was me....still learning.
I have decided to post the answer to my own question from a post i found from  someone called Gavros:

If you are using the motioneyeos image, you can fix this by doing the following:

ssh into your device using putty.

create this file using the nano command:

nano /data/etc/userinit.sh
add the below line into the userinit.sh file

v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl horizontal_flip=1

save and reboot your device.

Thanks Gavros worked for me problem sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the "motion" program but not under motioneyeos.  I was able to flip the image by putting the above mentioned "v4l2-ctl" command into /etc/rc.local and reboot.  Works great!